# JavaScript - how can I pre-fill a form in a way that the set value will be displayed by JavaScript on first load?

Tags: javascript, forms

I am still not familiar with JavaScript. I have a form with some data that I prefill like `value="60"` users can change that.

On page load I get the "60" in the form, but JS seems not to process it.

I like have the pre-filled form numbers displayed by JavaScript, so that the ***So you want to make....*** shows already on page load with all the data

It's probably a minor problem, what I tried so far with i.e. typeof etc. didn't work.

```js
let name = "pizza";
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = name;

function showMsg() {

  var many = document.getElementById('howMany').valueAsNumber;
  var weight = document.getElementById('weight').valueAsNumber;
  var water = document.getElementById('water').valueAsNumber;
  var yeast = document.getElementById('yeast').valueAsNumber;
  var oil = document.getElementById('oil').valueAsNumber;
  var salt = document.getElementById('salt').valueAsNumber;
  let myText = "<p><hr><p>The method is simple, but takes some ... and so on...";



  document.getElementById('intro').innerHTML = 'So you want to make ' + many + ' pizza of ' + weight + 'g each, here is what you need:<p>';
  document.getElementById('Flour').innerHTML = 'Flour: ' + ((many * weight) / (100 + water) * 100).toFixed(0) + 'g';
  document.getElementById('Water').innerHTML = 'Water: ' + ((many * weight) / (100 + water) * (water - oil)).toFixed(0) + 'g';
  document.getElementById('Salt').innerHTML = 'Salt: ' + (((many * weight) / (100 + water) * 100) / 100 * salt).toFixed(1) + 'g';
  document.getElementById('Oil').innerHTML = 'Oil: ' + (((many * weight) / (100 + water) * 100) / 100 * oil).toFixed(1) + 'g';
  document.getElementById('Yeast').innerHTML = 'Yeast: ' + (((many * weight) / (100 + water) * 100) / 100 * yeast).toFixed(2) + 'g';
  document.getElementById('more').innerHTML = myText;
}
```

```css
input {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px !important;
}

input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

input[type="number"] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield !important;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  padding: 2px;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  text-align: left;
  padding: 2px 0;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<h3>
  Dough Calculator
</h3>


<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">How many pizza you want?</div>
  <div class="grid-item"><input type="number" id="howMany" name="howMany" value="3" size="3" onkeyup="showMsg()">pieces</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Size per (typically 200-300g)</div>
  <div class="grid-item"><input type="number" id="weight" name="weight" value="250" size="4" onkeyup="showMsg()">g</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Water (typically 60%)</div>
  <div class="grid-item"><input type="number" id="water" name="water" value="60" size="2" onkeyup="showMsg()">%</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Salt (typically 2%)</div>
  <div class="grid-item"><input type="number" id="salt" name="salt1" size="2" value="2" onkeyup="showMsg()">%</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Oil (optional) (typically 0-5%) </div>
  <div class="grid-item"><input type="number" id="oil" name="oil" value="0" size="2" onkeyup="showMsg()">%</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Yeast (typically 0.05% dry yeast)</div>
  <div class="grid-item"><input type="number" id="yeast" name="yeast" value="0.05" size="4" onkeyup="showMsg()">%</div>
</div>

<p><span id="intro"></span></p>
<span id="Flour"></span><br>
<span id="Water"></span><br>
<span id="Salt"></span><br>
<span id="Oil"></span><br>
<span id="Yeast"></span><br>
<p><span id="more"></span></p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yello/5gosvp2L/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just run the function when the body is loaded with:

```
<body onload="showMsg()">
<!-- your input-->
</bod>
```

Comment: Very easy and works perfectly. Thank you! I forked it here: https://jsfiddle.net/yello/mrLjva9x/

Answer (score 2):

You basically have a number of inputs with a pre-filled value, and an `onkeyup` event handler that displays a summary, and your question boils down to "why doesn't the onkeyup handler fire on page load?"

The answer is that page load and key up are different events, so the handler for one will not fire for the other.

I would suggest that you add the same handler for page load:

```
window.addEventListener('load', showMsg)
```

Comment: I should have given you BA. When I place your string inside the <script> tags it works perfectly. The other code works perfectly too - on jsfiddle - but not inside my picoCMS page due the the <body> tag. Did not work in Wordpress either. 
But you have already so many BA so I leave it as is (unless you protest).

Answer (score 0):

By JS you mean to querySelector?
If so make sure you querySelect the Input itself and not the parent div, because in your jsfiddle it seem to work fine when I do querySelector(someinput).value

And btw, don't post jsfiddle, post a code sample so in the future people could reference your issue.

Comment: Sorry, I meant JavaScript - I corrected the error.